# Count 2 different date fields in a single query

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I have 2 different date fields, 1 when the case was created and the other when the case completed. I am trying to count total cases and total completions in say 2023.

Whenever I run my query and set the where field, both columns return the same figure.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cases,
       COUNT(IF(YEAR(tbl_lead.CompDate) = '2023', 1, NULL)) AS Completed,
       tbl_lead.LeadSource
FROM tbl_lead
WHERE YEAR(tbl_lead.CompDate) = '2023'
GROUP BY tbl_lead.LeadSource
```

I guess what I'm trying to do is count all records for 2023 as cases, then count how many of those have completed in 2023. Is it impossible?

It should output as:

| Cases | Completed | LeadSource |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 500 | Google |
| 2000 | 700 | Facebook |

Whereas it currently outputs:

| Cases | Completed | LeadSource |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 500 | Google |
| 700 | 700 | Facebook |

Thank you

Comment: Also it looks like you're attempting to aggregate more records in your Cases fields. I'd follow Mureinik's request as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current query only refers to CompDate but in your question you refer to two different date columns. Is this what you are looking for:

```
SELECT SUM(CreateDate >= '2023-01-01' AND CreateDate < '2024-01-01') AS cases,
       SUM(CompDate >= '2023-01-01' AND CompDate < '2024-01-01') AS Completed,
       LeadSource
FROM tbl_lead
WHERE (CreateDate >= '2023-01-01' AND CreateDate < '2024-01-01')
   OR (CompDate >= '2023-01-01' AND CompDate < '2024-01-01')
GROUP BY LeadSource
```

Comment: That is perfect, thank you so much for your help, its really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With this `where` condition, all the rows in the query are of cases completed in 2023 (i.e, match the condition in the `if`), so both `count`s will return the same result. Drop the `where` clause and you should be OK:

```sql
Select
    count(*) As cases,
    Count(If(Year(tbl_lead.CompDate) = '2023', 1, Null)) As Completed,
    tbl_lead.LeadSource
From
    tbl_lead
Group By
    tbl_lead.LeadSource
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mureinik. I had tried that but the cases column then shows all records for every year, not just 2023 unfortunately. Thank you though

Comment: @gary not sure I'm following. Can you edit your question with some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it?

Comment: The sample data of what shows and what should show is on there now.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a column (lets call it is_completed) that indicates whether a case is completed or not, in this case, try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cases,
       sum(is_completed) AS Completed,
       tbl_lead.LeadSource
FROM tbl_lead
WHERE YEAR(tbl_lead.CompDate) = '2023'
GROUP BY tbl_lead.LeadSource
```